# Angular animate + $templateCache

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have SPA which uses ngAnimate. If this app works without $templateCache animation work fine, but if I try to load templates from $templateCache animation does not work. 
Maybe if application uses $templateCache need add some config...

How can I fix this issue ?

My Views

```
angular.module('Views', ['views/index.html']);
angular.module("views/index.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("index.html", '<.... html index tpl  ....>');
}]);
```

App

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'Views'
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: How do you load from $templateCache? show the code.